# Broken Link Checker

Tags: asp.net, broken-links

I'm looking for a Visual Studio 2010 extension to check broken links in my ASP.Net projects? I know we can upload our website and then check through sites like http://validator.w3.org/checklink but would prefer to check prior to uploading to our test/production servers.

Comment: with out fully run the site its impossible to really find all possible broken links. For the easy one all ready the vs is warning you.

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows box you can use [Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html). It's free and can run on local sites:

> **Is Xenu better than a web-based service?**
>
> - Xenu can check intranets or local sites on http://localhost

Answer (score 0):

The [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) software can do that and a whole lot more.